# C read file line by line to dynamic array fails but with static array it works?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I try to read a file line by line to that dynamic array:

```
//r = rows (max. chars of one line), c = column (lines of file)
char *file_content[r];
for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    file_content[i] = (char*)calloc(c,sizeof(char));
}
```

readfile.c

```
void readFile(char *file_name, char **file_content) {
    char const* const fileName = file_name; 
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r"); 

    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(file_content[i], 512 + 1, file)) { //512+1 for null termination
        /* get rid of ending \n from fgets */
        file_content[i][strlen(file_content[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

So this code works perfectly with a static array like file_content[500][500] but with my dynamic array from above a

```
printf("%s", file_content[0]);
```

prints random content of the file.

I don't know how I should debug my problem, I'm a beginner..

Comment: The posted code isn't complete, so no one can answer why it's failing.  For example, what is the values of `r` and `c` in the code you did post.

Comment: Ah forgot that, r = rows, c = column

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/oRHuv1) you should just show the complete program where you have the issue, these snippets don't show your problem

Comment: Quote: "//r = rows (max. chars of one line), c = column (lines of file)" Hmm... r is "the number of lines" and c is "max char per line"

Comment: `512 + 1` is wrong. It must be `c`, i.e. the amount of chars `calloc`ed

Comment: What is the **values** of `r` and `c` ?

Comment: You should : 1. Compile using -Wall -Wextra -Werror, 2. Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or even [GDB](http://gnu.org/s/gdb) and remove every single memory leak. (Then you should not have any bug - only algorithm errors)

Comment: Your problem is that you have set `r` to 17, while the correct value is 43.